# How do I align my radiobuttons so that they seem to be in a column in Android?

Tags: android

[image: my display]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MBTITest" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/IE"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="What would you rather\n do on a Friday night?"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioI"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stay home and\n watch movies"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
             />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioE"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Go to a party"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp" >
    </View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SN"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Which would you\nmore likely say?"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Experiences speak \n louder than words"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioN"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="I think more about the\nfuture than the past"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp" >
    </View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp" >
    </View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp" >
    </View>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm working on my first project and I'm having trouble making my radio buttons align while trying to work with text sizes at the same time.  I'm kind of a noob at this and would appreciate any help.  I have tried messing with the gravities but to no avail I am here again.

Comment: It isn't easier to use a Spinner? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: better use

```
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
```

on your LinearLayouts instead of that View. (Depending on orientation you can use Left/Right, Top/Bottom)

second: use

```
android:weightSum="3"
```

for your LinearLayouts.

Then use the

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

for your items in the LinearLayouts.

You can experiment with those attributes and numbers.

This should fix your problem if I didn't misunderstand it.

Comment: Or he can use `TableLayout`

Comment: For that he could use almost all kinds of Layouts. I was just focusing on the problem